# Cert-manager ClusterIssuer undefined on EKS cluster with Cilium installed as CNI. Error: Post \"": Address is not allowed" "key"="clusterissuername"

Tags: amazon-eks, cert-manager, cilium

I installed cert manager with helm and kustomize but once it's deployed there's an error from the ClusterIssuer that use ACME as you can see in the image below:

And when I do `kubectl get clusterissuer` I can see there is absolutely no state defined and the READY field is empty.

My ClusterIssuer manifest:

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: acme-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: abdiakhate@example.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: acme-prod-account-key
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          route53:
            region: us-east-1
            accessKeyID: AKIAS2ETUR
            secretAccessKeySecretRef:
              name: credentials-secret
              key: secret-access-key
        selector:
          dnsZones:
            - "exemple.net"
```

My cert-manager yaml

```
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: cert-manager
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: cert-manager
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  source:
    repoURL: 'https://charts.jetstack.io'
    targetRevision: v1.7.1
    chart: cert-manager
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - values.yaml
      values: |
        installCRDs: true
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

I think maybe the cilium is the main cause of my issue and are looking for help.
Thank you in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WUmf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xregg.png

Answer (score 0):

You should set certmanager-webhook hostnetwork to true. Then it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).